# ITextSharp returning zero for measuring string size

Tags: c#, itext

I have the following function:

```
private float MeasureText(string text)
{
    BaseFont font = BaseFont.CreateFont();

    return font.GetWidthPoint(text, 10.0f);
}
```

My problem is, no matter what I pass into this function, it `GetWidthPoint` is always returning `0`. Am I using this function wrong?

Comment: What font is being created? What do you get if you actually specify a font?

Comment: I didn't want to specify a font. I just wanted to use ITextSharp's default font.

Comment: I don't think `BaseFont.CreateFont()` does what you want. I think it just creates you a dummy font instance.

Comment: @Icemanind - works for me: `BaseFont.CreateFont().GetWidthPoint("text", 10.0f);` returns **16.12**. @TyCobb - `BaseFont.CreateFont()` returns `BaseFont.HELVETICA`.

Comment: @kuujinbo - I don't get it then. That function I posted is verbatim. No edits. It seems like you are doing the same thing I am. Maybe its my iTextSharp version.

Comment: Yes, we're doing exactly the same thing, and I copied your sample method and tested to make sure. Source code says `BaseFont.CreateFont()` was implemented in version 2.1.1 (IIRC that's equal to iTextSharp 4.1.1), and the oldest version I have, 4.1.6, is implemented exactly the same as the latest version. (5.5.4.0) Couldn't hurt to try and update your version.

Comment: Do you get an exception about an AFM not being found if you try using the font? If so, that would mean that you are missing the Adobe Font Metrics file for Helvetica. The Adobe Font Metrics file is where iTextSharp finds the metrics to calculate the width. If it's not there (or if its information is incorrect), no measurement can be done.